# Why can't I comment out this string?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode, comments

I'm unable to comment-out and compile the following line of code with /* */, within the XCode editor.  I distilled this example down from a more complex string used in an XPath query:

the string itself seems fine:

```
NSString* s = @"//*//";
```

won't compile for me:

```
/*
NSString* s = @"//*//";
*/
```

XCode 4.4.  I'll file a radar if anyone can confirm I'm not being stupid.

**EDIT**:  nice to see that the SO syntax highlighter also exhibits an issue with this...

**EDIT**:  okay, I filed a bug report with Apple.  Thanks.

**EDIT**: Per Rob's answer below, this is NOT a bug :)  Thanks for explaining it, Rob; totally makes sense now.

Comment: That's interesting, \ing the characters in the string seems to fix it but that isn't exactly a solution... it's kind of a pain.

Comment: That syntax highlighting breaks is not surprising to me.  That the compiler choked on it is surprising to me.  I guess the syntax highlighter must share the compiler front-end...

Comment: I think rob mayoff is right, so I removed my previous comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a compiler bug. The double-quote character `"` has no special meaning inside a comment, so the preprocessor doesn't pay any attention to it.  The preprocessor just ends the comment as soon as it sees the `*/` characters.

The best way to comment out a section of code is to put `//` at the beginning of each line.  A `//` comment ends at the next newline.  Xcode has a menu command (shortcut: ⌘`/`) that will comment or uncomment your selected lines by inserting or removing `//` at the start of each line.

Comment: And even a keyboard shortcut-- command-slash with a block highlighted.

Comment: @BenZotto I was on my iPad when I wrote that so I wasn't sure of the shortcut.  Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

It detects and end comment in `@"//*//";` I don't know of any editor that allows nesting of block comments (I know that's not what you're doing, but same issue). Notice how even the syntax highlighter on SO screws up.